# How to sum data by interval of date (10 min) in R

Tags: r, time-series

i got a set of data (1 point each minute) that i want to sum by time but when i apply this code:

```
library(xts)
a2.xts <- xts(data$data, as.POSIXct(data$time))  
a3.xts <- period.apply(a2.xts, INDEX=endpoints(a2.xts, "mins", k=10), FUN=sum)
head(a3.xts)
```

i get

```
2016-11-07 11:35:00   23
2016-11-08 11:45:00   56
2016-11-08 11:55:00   66
2016-11-08 12:05:00   32
2016-11-08 12:15:00   23
```

but i want it to start from 11:40, 11:50 and so on not 35,45.
Thank you

Comment: Problem is you do not have observations at `11:40`, `11:50`, etc. What you can do is to `merge` with an index that contain those times. Then, the data at those times will be `NA`. Then use `sum` with `na.rm=TRUE`.

Comment: i have data at 11:40 and every minute. concerning NAs iit was a misktake of my behalf, problem was corrected, thank you

Comment: [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36827937/496488) might be helpful.